# Fill Combobox with combined columns access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, combobox, multiple-columns, items

How can I combine the columns "Firstname" "Lastname" from my **access** database "contacts.accdb" filling combobox?? I have already loaded the `dataset` +`datagridview` into another form in the project..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple but complete example :

```
Dim con as New OledbConnection = connectionstringhere
Dim cmd as New OleDbCommand("Select * from tablenamehere",con)
Dim dr as OledbDataReader=cmd.ExecuteReader
While dr.read
Dim FnameAndLname as string = dr(0).ToString + " " + dr(1).ToString 'Assuming the FirstName is the 1st and the LastName is the 2nd Column of the table
MyConboBox.Items.Add(FnameAndLname)
End while
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I think you might want to add & " " & between the first and last Names.

Comment: @Mary,yeah,added it,incase the OP wants a SPACE in-between

Comment: `Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Contactos.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
        cn.Open()
        Dim cm As New OleDbCommand("select * from ContactosTabla", cn)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            ComboBox3.Items.Add(dr(1).ToString + " " + dr(2).ToString) 'Assuming the FirstName is the 1st and the LastName is the 2nd Column of the table
        End While
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()`

Comment: please mark the answer as answer and upvote it if it helped